# Import string from javascript file (react/nextJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, next.js

I have a file "test.js" in my "/constants" folder with the following content:

```
const test = "test!"

export default test
```

My page in the "/pages" folder should read the string from "test.js" and print it

```
import { test } from "../constants/test"

export default function Home() {
    console.log("imported string: " + test)
}
```

If I run it the browser I get the following output:

"imported string: undefined"

Why is it not reading the string from the file? The path is correct. VSCode autocomplete even finds the file while typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting the constant test as the default export, therefor your import statement should be changed from

```
import { test } from "../constants/test"
```

to

```
import test from "../constants/test"
```

NOTE: the {} imports are for NON-default exports

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `import { test }`    then you should use `export test` instead of using `default`
Because right now you're telling javascript to find specific export, not default.

Comment: thanks, this works as well. But I think the syntax is "export { test }"

Comment: both the same `export {test}` and inline version `export test = "mytest";`